# kubectl apply -f pod.yaml is abnormal

Tags: kubernetes, runtime, kubectl, kata-containers

When I used kubectl apply -f pod.yaml, I found that the corresponding pod did not succeed

When I use kubectl describe pod nginx-sandbox-ori it shows

```html
Successfully assigned default/nginx-sandbox-ori to localhost.localdomain
Container image "xxx" already present on machine
Created container alpine
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: failed to mount "/run/kata-containers/shared/containers/alpine/rootfs" to "/run/kata-containers/alpine/rootfs",with error: ENOENT: No such file or directory: unknown
```

I use kata-container as container runtime
And I started a kind as RuntimeClass, set the name as kata

“/run/kata-containers/shared/containers/alpine/rootfs”
I found that this folder does not exist on the machine

Comment: forget it, In the confidential container solution, you cannot directly pull the image to the local through other tools

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue. I checked `/run/kata-containers/shared/`. It does not have any directory `containers`. It only has a directory called `sandboxes`. Do we have to pull and unpack the image manually on the node for this to work?